# du result of directory larger than sum of files in that directory

Tags: linux, directory, disk-usage

use `du -a` in a given directory, but the disk usage of directory is larger than sum of all file's disk usage in that directory. why is that? From the man page, I assume that du command return the disk usage of given directory or file. I tried in sereval different directory, it's always larger. and there is no hidden files in all this directorys.
this is the result I got from running that command in a directory.

```
4       ./v
4       ./ls1.c
8       ./ls2.c
4       ./chown.c
24      .
```

The total is 24, but I expected 20 (the sum of the values above).

this is the result I got from running `ls -al` command in the same directory.

```
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 2 zxy zxy 4096 Oct  4 16:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 zxy zxy 4096 Oct  4 13:09 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 zxy zxy  981 Oct  2 15:34 chown.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 zxy zxy  651 Oct  1 13:50 ls1.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 zxy zxy 4133 Oct  2 21:30 ls2.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 zxy zxy    5 Oct  4 16:11 v
```

thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what numbers you are comparing (`28` and `24`, or each individual file?). Each file uses 4 Kb of actual disk space, because that's the smallest allocatable space on that filesystem. The `ls2.c` file is larger than 4 Kb, so there's two 4 Kb blocks allocated for it, hence `8` in the output from `du`.  Since I'm not entirely certain what numbers you are asking about, I'm not turning this into an answer.

Comment: Further, in du, `.` (the directory itself) includes itself in the count (also at least one block), but not `..` (the parent directory). Everything is in 4's because du (by default) shows KB, not blocks (whose size can vary between different file system types). `ls` does appear to count precisely all the things it lists, including `..`, so `ls -l`, `ls -Al` and `ls -al` give three different results for `total` in the presence of hidden files: this might be considered a bug, or a feature.

Comment: so the extra 4 the du command showed is from . itself right? and I have another problem, why the blocks in stat command is different from du command?

Comment: That should be a separate question, but it is brief: in stat, *block* means *sector*. You'll need to look up what the format options mean, but try: `stat -c '%b %B %o %n' *`.

Comment: Thank you sir. I'll look it up.

Comment: I think the question is clear. The sum is 24, but the OP expected 20. If this is correct, can you edit the question to make it clearer.